# How can I convert this $_POST statement from PHP into coldfusion

Tags: php, javascript, coldfusion, reference

I'd like to catch spammers by using the web form obfuscation method described [here](http://www.wilhelser.com/2012/04/stop-bot-submitted-form-spam/).

The only issue is that I'm on [ColdFusion](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion-family.html) servers and my `mailto` forms are in cfm.

```
if( !isset($_POST['name'])) { die("No Direct Access"); }  // Make sure the form has      actually been submitted

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$spam = $_POST['username']; // This is our Honeypot field

if($spam) {  // If the Honeypot field has been filled in
die("No spamming allowed!"); 
} else {
// Process the form like normal
}
```

**(Update: Code from comments)**

My form:

```
<tr style="display: none;"> 
    <td> <li id="user" style="display: none;"> 
            <label for="spamCatch">spamCatch</label> 
            <input type="text" name="spamCatch"> 
         </li> 
    </td> 
</tr>
```

My mail cfm:

```
<cfparam name="form.Notform1" default=""> 
<cfset spam = false> 
<cfif structKeyExists(form,'name')> 
    <cfset spamCheck = form.spamCheck> 
    <cfif spam> 
         No spam. 
         <cfabort> 
    <cfelse> 
        <cfmail from="title" to="email" subject="subject" server="servername" type="html"> 
            <style type="text/css"> 
            <cfinclude template="../css/cfForms.css"> 
            </style> 
             HTML HERE FROM FORM 
        </cfmail> 
    </cfif> 
</cfif>
```

Comment: So what's the question exactly? You want us to write code for you?

Comment: there is at least one downside to that technique: the poor blind people who use web-readers might fill the honeypot-field, and get that friendly 'No spamming allowed bitch!' in return, whilst not knowing what they did wrong.  I'd use this technique to aid a possible-spam-score counting system.

Comment: I don't know the coldfusion equivalent. Can you give me a resource that has the answer to this, or if you know if maybe you can help? I'm not asking for handouts but this is a Q&A site.

Comment: In ColdFusion `POST` values are stored in a system scope named `FORM`. Take a look at [Working with action pages](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6eb7.html) for examples. To determine if a field exists, see [StructKeyExists](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fbb.html). To check the length of a string, see [String Functions Section](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1a60c-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6a3a).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the basic concept. I would highly suggest looking at [learncfinaweek.com](http://learncfinaweek.com)

```
<cfset spam = false>
// run code to check for spam
<cfif structKeyExists(form,'name')>
    <cfset name = form.name>
    <cfset email = form.email>
    <cfset username = form.username>

    <cfif spam>
        No spam.<cfabort>
    <cfelse>
        <cfmail to="email" from="email" subject="email">
            text
        </cfmail>
    </cfif>
<cfelse>
    No Direct Access.<cfabort>
</cfif>
```

Comment: is that <cfif spam> allowed?

Comment: You need to check if the key is defined for email and username. Also the username variable should be stored as spam per his example.

Comment: @snarf_narfer it's equivalent to `spam NEQ 0`

Comment: Spam will always exist, hence this will always fail, you want to check if it has a value or not

Comment: @matthewbourke he didn't post his spam code, so I assumed he would pass a true/false as spam. This wouldn't always fail if he had his spam code included.

Comment: @snarf_narfer spam would be a boolean value. You set spam equal to either true or false based on your own logic.

Comment: which is the way this is set up right? @MattBusche. The way I see it, if it sees the field is filled it stops it.

Comment: huh? If spam is true then it doesn't process. If spam is false it sends an email.

Comment: `<cfif spam>` = `<cfif spam EQ true>` it's not checking just to see if the variable exists.

Comment: I'd imagine spam is simply a text field hidden, so it should be empty string, a spam bot will fill it out by mistake, it might enter simply a 0 a 1 or some long string etc, I'd use a len(spam) this way it will stop if its filled out at all

Comment: Using this code I get a "no direct access" whatever way I fill the form out. With or without the "spam field" filled out.

Comment: do you have a field called name in your form? is this page being ran after you submit the form? If either of those are false then that's why it's not working.

Comment: is your name field really called name?

Comment: My form:

    <tr style="display: none;">
    <td>
    <li id="user" style="display: none;">                                   <label for="spamCatch">spamCatch</label>
  <input type="text" name="spamCatch">
 </li>
 </td>
 </tr>

Comment: my mail cfm: <cfparam name="form.Notform1" default="">

<cfset spam = false>
<cfif structKeyExists(form,'name')>
 <cfset spamCheck = form.spamCheck>
      <cfif spam>
      No spam.
        <cfabort>
    <cfelse>
<cfmail 
from="title" 
to="email"
subject="subject" 
server="servername"
type="html">
<style type="text/css">
<cfinclude template="../css/cfForms.css">
</style> 

HTML HERE FROM FORM
</cfmail>
</cfif>
</cfif>

Comment: @snarf_narfer so the key `name` does not exist in the form. Change `name` to `spamCheck` and it will work. These are all really basic questions that a tutorial would really help with.

Comment: I changed it and it sends the form regardless.

<cfset spam = false>
<cfif structKeyExists(form,'spamCheck')>
 <cfset spamCheck = form.spamCheck>
      <cfif spam>
      No spam.
        <cfabort>
    <cfelse>
<cfmail

Answer (score 0):

spam will always exist if its a hidden field, so check if its empty

```
<cfif !structkeyexists(form, "name")>
    <cfdump var="no direct access" abort>
</cfif>

<cfparam name="form.name" default="">
<cfparam name="form.email" default="">
<cfparam name="form.spam" default=""> 

<cfif len(form.spam)>
    <cfdump var="No spamming allowed!" abort>
<cfelse>

</cfif>
```

Comment: A hidden field is not likely to be named spam.  It wasn't clear in @Matt's answer, but defining spam is up to the developer.  If you want to do an additional check besides the form variable, you could always see if cgi.http_referrer is the expected value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<cfset spam = len(trim(form.userName))>` Read below for the explanation.

In PHP [an empty string is considered false, and any string with a length is considered true](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php). ColdFusion does not have the same implicit boolean conversion.

```
// PHP
var_dump((bool) "");        // bool(false)
var_dump((bool) "foo");     // bool(true)
<!--- CFML --->
yesNoFormat("") <!--- ERROR: cannot convert the value "''" to a boolean --->
yesNoFormat("foo") <!--- ERROR: cannot convert the value "foo" to a boolean --->


$spam = $_POST['username'];
if($spam){}
```

is the same as

```
<cfset spam = form.userName>
<cfif spam></cfif>
```

that will produce the same **cannot convert the value "''" to a boolean** error if the form field is empty, which you hope it will be.

what you want to do is check for the length of the honey pot field or check for an empty string.

```
<cfif len(trim(form.userName))>
<!--- or <cfif trim(form.userName) neq ""> --->
no spam <cfabort>
</cfif>
```

if you still want to use the spam variable you can do this:

```
<cfset spam = len(trim(form.userName))>
<cfif spam>
    No spam<cfabort>
</cfif>
```

Right now you have `<cfset spam = false>` but then the code doesn't do anything to change the Boolean value. If you change that line to `<cfset spam = len(trim(form.userName))>` your code will work.